# SMTP message rate control on Ubuntu 8.04, preferably with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, spam

Maybe I am chasing a bug but I am trying to set up a smtp proxy of sorts. I have a postfix server which receives all the email for a collection of servers/clients. It them uses a smarthost (relayhost=...) to forward it's mail to our corporate MTA. I would like to limit the number of messages an individual server can relay to prevent swamping the corporate MTA. Postfix has a program called "anvil" that is capable of tracking stats about mail to be used for such things but it doesn't seem to be executed. I ran "inotifywait -m /usr/lib/postfix/anvil" while I started postfix and sent a number of messages through it from a remote server. inotifywait indicated anvil was never run. Anyone gotten postfix/anvil rate controls to work?

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
myhostname = site-server-q9
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost = Out outgoing mail relay
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 10.X.X.X
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 1
anvil_rate_time_unit = 1h
```

master.cf extract

```
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I used policyd which does just this sort of thing. I configured it to limit a single IP address to no more than 10000 messages an hour and 1 GB.
Below is a copy of the doc a wrote up for myself in case anyone finds it helpful.

---

#### Configuring postfix and policyd

After the packages have been installed  make the following changes to their configurations. In /etc/postfix/main.cf add the following line

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

In /etc/postfix-policyd.conf

- change `WHITELISTING=1` to `WHITELISTING=0`
- change `GREYLISTING=1` to `GREYLISTING=0`
- change `SENDERTHROTTLE=0` to `SENDERTHROTTLE=1`
- change `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_TEMP_REJECT=1` to `QUOTA_EXCEEDED_TEMP_REJECT=0`
- change `SENDER_QUOTA_REJECTION="Quota Exceeded."`  to `SENDER_QUOTA_REJECTION="Quota Exceeded, 10,000 messages/hour max!"`
- change `SENDER_SIZE_REJECTION="Message size too big."` to `SENDER_SIZE_REJECTION="Message size too big. 10Mb per message or 1 Gb/hour max!"`
- change `SENDERMSGLIMIT=512` to `SENDERMSGLIMIT=10000`
- change `SENDERRCPTLIMIT=3600` to `SENDERRCPTLIMIT=10000`
- change `SENDERQUOTALIMIT=250000000`  to `SENDERQUOTALIMIT=1000000000`
- change `SENDERMSGSIZE=10240000` to `SENDERMSGSIZE=50000000`
- change `SENDER_INACTIVE_EXPIRE=31d` to `SENDER_INACTIVE_EXPIRE=1h`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly interesting for your implementation:

```
default_destination_concurrency_limit (default: 20)

    The default maximal number of parallel deliveries to the same destination. This is the default limit for delivery via the lmtp(8), pipe(8), smtp(8) and virtual(8) delivery agents. With per-destination recipient limit > 1, a destination is a domain, otherwise it is a recipient.

    Use transport_destination_concurrency_limit to specify a transport-specific override, where transport is the master.cf name of the message delivery transport.
```

Answer (score 1):

Anvil was really meant to limit incoming message rates, not limit outgoing.  Think of it as a crude DoS filter.

You might want to look at the settings that pertain to the [qmgr](http://www.postfix.org/qmgr.8.html) portion of postfix.  Specifically, you might want to set your [concurrency](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#initial_destination_concurrency) limits to something very low, and your [wait-around-in-the-queue times](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#maximal_queue_lifetime) very high.  **You'll want to set the [rate of delivery to something that has a large(r) delay](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_destination_rate_delay),** and also want to lower the number of delivery processes in master.cf.

Have you [looked at using qshape](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html) to determine what will be an acceptable rate for your internal MTA?

Comment: My goal is not to slow anything down, I just want to prevent run away process from taking out the corporate server. That is the deal I made with the exchange team for their services. Mail still needs to be snappy.
I reconfigured postfix for local delivery and repeated the test. Message are still ignoring the limit.

Comment: I figured it out!! Anvil doesn't get feed/process data about clients that are in "mynetworks = ..."
I changed it to mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 and the limit is being obeyed.

Answer (score 0):

Anvil does logging for postfix , Ive added below to main.cf and seems to work for me

```
#### Prevent server sending excess mail from clients add to /etc/postfix/main.cf
####
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time = 120s
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 2s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 
#### End Prevent server sending excess mail
```