# Postfix Stagger/Rate Limit Outbound Mail

Tags: centos, postfix, email

We have a server that sends our weekly newsletter to subscribers, To prevent people like Hotmail or Yahoo from blocking us due to sending too many simultaneous emails to them, Is there a way we can stagger email, or rate-limit outbound emails from postfix?

Keep in mind, I dont want the mailserver to stop queueing mail or accepting new messages, Simply defer delivery if there are more then 3-4 messages per destination domain/ipaddress, or something similar.

**Note:** I dont want a Sender Throttle, as described in a similar question, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/32368/smtp-message-rate-control-on-ubuntu-8-04-preferably-with-postfix).
I'm looking more for a recipient throttle but haven't had any luck finding out how to do so with PolicyD or Anvil services, and was wondering if anyone else has accomplished such a task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the deadbeats trick:

main.cf:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
deadbeats_destination_concurrency_limit = 50
```

master.cf:

```
deadbeats unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_connect_timeout=5 -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 smtp_connect_timeout=2
```

transport.cf:

```
hotmail.com             deadbeats:
yahoo.com               deadbeats:
earthlink.net           deadbeats:
freemail.com.au         deadbeats:
```

Answer (score 2):

Should read:

```
deadbeats    unix    -    -    n    -    -    smtp 
    -o smtp_connect_timeout=5 
    -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 
    -o smtp_connect_timeout=2
```

And you should restart Postfix

Answer (score 2):

To supplement rkthkr's post, you will need to run postmap on the transports file ([man transport(5)](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html))

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport.cf
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add in

main.cf

```
deadbeats_destination_recipient_limit = 5
```

for having 5 recipients per session

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that rkthr's suggested master.cf of

```
deadbeats unix - - n - - smtp -o smtp_connect_timeout=5 -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 smtp_connect_timeout=2
```

has the 'smtp_connect_timeout' parameter mistakenly listed twice.  If for some reason you wanted to have it listed twice, you would need another '-o' as described in user40991's answer.