# How to configure Postfix to send bulk email at a "reasonable" rate per scond

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

Maybe a postfix newbie question.

Our linux server is properly set up with an SPF record, and we don't send mass email at the moment.
But, is there a simple way to configure the postfix mail queue, when it recieves a request to send 1000s of emails to send at 1 or 2 a second?

Comment: thanks - found this there -- http://serverfault.com/questions/32368/smtp-message-rate-control-on-ubuntu-8-04-preferably-with-postfix

Comment: yep, was just about to post same link =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tune `default_destination_concurrency_limit` and, possibly, per-transport concurrency limits, although defaults should work fine.

See [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_destination_concurrency_limit) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this: [postfix slow transport](http://www.pubbs.net/postfix/200909/98526/).  You can set those options for the default transport (smtp) if you really want it to be for everything.

Comment: Sorry, link no longer resolves. :(